# Take a course at/in/from?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I already know we use "take a course *in* history" is used to indicate taking subjects. But how about indicating university? Say:

```
"My friend took a course + (from/at/in) + Utrecht university last year" ?
```

Comment: to take a course +on/in + X University.

Comment: Take a course: In history, at (a) university, with friends, from Monday to Friday, on weekdays, by night....and so on!

Comment: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/course

Comment: **To take a course at a university** or **X University**. Utrecht University, both caps.

Comment: Usually, when the idea of location is used, we use **at**. To meet friends at the station. To see you at home. To study at university.